# Why is the Erigon client's archival node size significantly smaller than alternatives?

Tags: storage, nodes, archive-node, disk-space

I was reading the archival node requirements on this [article](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/run-a-node/#requirements) and the Erigon execution client is much smaller than Besu, Geth, and Nethermind (2.5TB+ vs. 12TB+). How is it so much smaller?

Answer (score 0):

It's the database. There's a very detailed [description of the different layout](https://github.com/ledgerwatch/erigon/blob/devel/docs/programmers_guide/db_walkthrough.MD) between erigon's and geth's database. If I had to sum it up I'd say that erigon is able to use storage space much more efficiently e.g. by using an own table for the *History of Accounts*. This is comparable to the concept of normalisation in relational databases, I guess. The database engines are also based on different data structures (lsm tree vs. b+ tree), but this has only a minor effect on the storage. However I'm also rather new to erigon's codebase and hope to see part 2 of [Giulio's article in that matter](https://medium.com/@giulio.rebuffo/turbo-geth-whats-different-the-database-5916e8ec834b). I'm sure he could explain it much better than me.